# How can I figure out if a background app is causing audio ducking?

Tags: iphone, audio

Frequently when I'm listening to podcasts in Overcast, and sometimes when I'm listening to music in Bandcamp, the audio volume drops for several seconds. There's no indication that I received a notification or anything like that.

Is it possible that this is caused by a badly-behaved background app playing silence or near-silence? Is there any way to tell when apps are playing audio? There are a few apps that show up in the battery usage list with "audio" as a battery usage reason that aren't audio apps and really have no business doing what they're doing, but I'm not sure how to figure out which ones if any are causing these ducking issues.

Comment: Try to disable Background App Refresh to see if the sound is still playing.